# Eshell will enter "Text is read only" and freeze

Tags: eshell

Basically I try to enable showing git branch I'm in in eshell buffer. The elisp I got works fine. But I will constantly run into "Text is read only " and have to kill the eshell buffer to start over.

```el
;; eshell promopt
(defun my-current-git-branch ()
  (let ((branch (car (loop for match in (split-string (shell-command-to-string "git branch") "\n")
                           when (string-match "^\*" match)
                           collect match))))
    (if (not (eq branch nil))
        (concat ":" (substring branch 2))
      "")))

(defun my-eshell-prompt ()
  (concat (propertize (abbreviate-file-name (eshell/pwd)) 'face 'eshell-prompt)
          (propertize (my-current-git-branch) 'face 'font-lock-function-name-face)
          (propertize " λ " 'face 'font-lock-constant-face)))

;; em-prompt
(setq eshell-prompt-function 'my-eshell-prompt)
```

I am using Arch Linux and Emacs25. Does anyone have any idea to solve or a better approach?

Comment: Did you update `eshell-prompt-regexp`?

Comment: Oops, that is the part I missed. How can I know the exact `eshell-prompt-regexp` value I want? Thx

Comment: I figured out it should be `(setq eshell-prompt-regexp "^[^#$]*:$# ")`. Do you want to put out answer or you just want me to quote it?    Thx very much

Comment: Go ahead and make an answer of it, if it works. I would think it should be something like `(setq eshell-prompt-regexp "^[^λ]+ λ ")` though.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @npostavs, the thing that I missed previously is you have to update `eshell-prompt-regexp` as you modified the eshell prompt. This is also vaguely mentioned in EmacsWiki: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellPrompt

In my case, you can add sth like `(setq eshell-prompt-regexp "^[^λ]+ λ ")`.

Comment: It's mentioned in the docstring of `eshell-prompt-function`.